# How to set the command prompt's color in Bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, colors

Browsing the last command's results in Bash is a bit hard because the command prompt and results are the same color. This makes it hard to separate the results of consecutive commands.

How do I change the color to pink for example?

Comment: You'll want to add color to the PS1 variable.

Comment: Yes, my current PS1 is PS1='\u:\w\$ ' which I do not know what does mean. How should I change it to colorize command prompt to pink with out loosing current settings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Rob is right; specifically, to change to light red (pink is not an available color):

```
PS1 = "\[\033[1;31m\]\u:\w\$\[\033[0m\] "
#      ^^^^^^^     ^^                    Begin/end ANSI escape
#             ^^^^^                      "light red foreground"
#                    ^^^^^^^             Your original prompt
#                           ^^^^^^^^^^^  Reset color back to default foreground
```

You need to use ANSI escape sequences (in this case `1;31m`, the code for "light red foreground") which are enclosed by `\[\033[` and `\]`.

**Edit:** Light purple may be closer to your desired color; the `PS1` change is left as an exercise for the reader.

[reference @ the linux documentation project](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html)

Comment: I'm not great with ansi codes, so I left the answer to someone else.

Comment: ANSI escape sequences begin with `\033` and go up to (including) `m`. The surrounding `\[` and `\]` are bash-specific and are required so that bash can keep track of where the cursor is (it expects anything inside these markers not to advance the cursor).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like an alternate solution you can create a small script for setting the terminal session PS1 colors without making them permanent (unless you wish for permanent colors follow Alex's solution).

If we create `yellow.sh` and save to `/usr/bin` directory, and then make the file executable with `chmod +x yellow.sh` we can then edit the `yellow.sh` and add the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

# Yellow color variable
ylw='\x1b[93m'

echo -e "${ylw}"
clear
```

Running this script will then change your terminal color to yellow. You can reset your PS1 color in the same way using this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

# Reset color to default
rst='\x1b[0m'

echo -e "${rst}"
clear
```

Here is a quick list of some color-code variables you can use.

```
black=$'\x1b[90m' # Dark gray. Not used much.
red=$'\x1b[91m'
green=$'\x1b[92m'
yellow=$'\x1b[93m'
blue=$'\x1b[94m'
purple=$'\x1b[95m'
cyan=$'\x1b[96m'
pink=$'\x1b[97m'
default=$'\x1b[0m' # Reset to default color.
```

Usage for common commands inside simple scripts:

```
echo -e "${red} $(ls $1) ${default}" # Argument would be the directory you want to list.
```

This can be done rather quickly depending on how you setup your colors to be used. The color codes I have provided are not all. Depending on what colors your terminal supports, you could use a range of 256 colors.