# How do I change the command prompt color of a MobaXTerm SSH terminal?

Tags: ssh, terminal, mobaxterm

I wanted to change the color of the command prompt 
`[xxx@xxx]$` from white on black background to light green on black background during a SSH session in MobaXTerm. I tried changing the color scheme in session>edit session>terminal but this command prompt color does not change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the command prompt's color in Bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/422071/how-to-set-the-command-prompts-color-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The software which draws the prompt on the server where you are connecting to with SSH needs to be configured to print color codes. If the remote shell is Bash, try e.g. http://ezprompt.net/